# Not getting ref value in custom input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I do have a parent custom component which I can't edit and I am using code like this.

`<MyInput>`//library component or component i will use in my main component

```js
import * as React from "react";

type Props = {
    value: string | null | undefined;
    label?: string | React.ReactNode;
    autofocus?:boolean
    ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
};

declare class MyInput extends React.Component<Props> {
    static defaultProps: {
        type: string;
    };
    handleFocus: () => void;
    render(): React.JSX.Element;
}

export { MyInput };
```

And in my  **main** component I am trying to use

```
function componentA(props: Props) {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
     <MyInput
       max={255}
       autofocus={true}
       ref={ref}
       onFocus={() => ref?.current?.select()}
       value={name}
       onChange={setName}
       placeholder={"sample Name"}
     />
```

2 problem am facing - First one is
I am getting type error in ref like this

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props | Readonly<Props>): Input', gave the following error.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type '(LegacyRef<Input> & RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) | undefined'.
      Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Input> & RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
        Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Input>'.
```

and the second issue is I am not getting the reference to the input element?

Comment: if i write normal input box like 
<input type="text" ref={ref} value={name} />
its working as expected and text is getting highlighted  @here. But not working in 
<myInput>

Comment: Have you tried ```forwardRef```?  [official docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)

Comment: First, `myInput` isn't a valid React component. React components are capitalized, so it ***should*** be `MyInput`. Second, please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the `MyInput` component so we can see where/how the ref is used, there is no `input` element in your posted code.

Comment: @DrewReese there is no input element in my code as well, i just tried with normal input element html and its working , so just want to convey that, thats why mentioned .For normal input html element its working , but not with the custom < myInput> component

Comment: The `MyInput` component needs to attach the ref to a DOM element so that it can be focused. Without this the ref is largely useless. The `forwardRef` utility is used with React function components since they are instanceless and ***need*** to have it forwarded. This is different from React class components that handle refs "natively". In your code the only thing missing is actually attaching the ref to a DOM element. This is the [mcve] I was requesting, how and where you use the passed ref in `MyInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React protects child nodes from being exposed via references passed from parent through props. Use [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef) to explicitly expose it:

```
type Props = {
  // ... as normal
};

export const MyInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({}, ref) => (
    <input ref={ref}/>
  )
);
```

```
function componentA(props: Props) {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
     <MyInput ref={ref} />
  );
}
```

Comment: can you help me in implementing same  in my above piece of code

Comment: Also how can i remove type error , if i give {ref as any}, no errror, but i know its not the right way

Comment: @midhunk edited the post to clarify. this work for me with no type errors